# How to properly add or manage a repeated User Story in Auzre DevOps's backlog?

Tags: sprint-backlog, sprint-planning, devops, azure-boards

A user story needs to happen each sprint, and I want it to handle it properly - whatever that may mean - within Azure DevOps. I am used to adding user stories for single-issue tickets but have never before had to do a ticket that gets repeated. Is it as simple as adding a new single-issue ticket every sprint, or can I set it up automatically?

Comment: I believe it'd be really important to understand the actual nature of this recurrent user story. What's the value this recurrent user story is adding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this might be a general issue, not related to Azure Devops backlog. I see multiple approaches here:

1. Add a separate Kanban board to the team for recurring items
2. Extract a member of the team to do operation stuff, as this item seems like an operational issue
3. Add item into the Sprint and SM should suggest a rotation mechanism to handle that item so it doesn't come into the yard of just one person.

Answer (score 0):

I have a a list of recurring tasks that I keep in a CSV file in an Azure DevOps repository, and then I run a scheduled pipeline job weekly to pull from that list and create a new story using the ADO API. It took me maybe 1/2 day to set up, and then I just need to update the CSV file if I want to add new recurring tasks.